# SearchView (Support) in FragmentActivity always null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've started messing around with fragments, as my app on tablets could be using space more efficiently.

Now, in my old app, I had a SearchView in the actionbar menu, that would show on ifRoom. I'm using the same code, but now the SearchView item is always null. I'm not looking for changing the menu items depending on active fragments or whatever, I just need the SearchView to function from the FragmentActivity.

FragmentActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.svPet);
    this.svPet = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    if(this.svPet != null)
    {
        this.svPet.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
        this.svPet.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

   return true;
}
```

main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

       <item
          android:id="@+id/svPet"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:titleCondensed="@string/search">
      </item>

      ...Some more items that are never shown as action and work correctly
</menu>
```

So, whenever the menu is being created, this.svPet stays null, the searchview is not displayed in the bar (even when there's more than enough room), and when I click on the item from the menu, my application crashes, saying there's a nullpointer on

```
this.svPet.setIconified(false);
```

in

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong? I'm probably overlooking something, but I just don't see what's wrong at the moment. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you have xml searchable configuration?

Comment: I don't see why I would need that, as it has always worked beautifully without it before. Is it mandatory when using a FragmentActivity?

Comment: no it's not mandatory,  but i thought that some broken searchable file could lead to null SearchView, btw is "searchItem" valid?

Comment: Yep, searchItem is valid

Answer (score 0):

some ideas

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
//SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
if (searchView != null) {
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            // do something with s, the entered string
            query = s;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "String entered is " +  s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

menu.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I need to use the support library tho, so wouldn't the code then be pretty much the same, exce[t for an added queryTextListener?

Answer (score 0):

So... after some digging I found that when using MenuItemCompat in combination with FragmentActivity, getActionView(searchItem) returns null. I think this is a bug in the support library, so I'll have to submit a bugreport for that. (Done, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76141&thanks=76141&ts=1410649918)

My workaround:
Instead of

```
this.svPet = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

I used

```
this.svPet = new SearchView(this);
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(searchItem, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(searchItem, this.svPet);
```

--Edit--
After some more looking around, I found that you can just use ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity, as ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity. When using that, you can use

```
this.svPet = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

as usual.